# Laravel: Best way to create logs to a User table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Users table and I want to add a field to the table that has an array of logs and each log as a `timestamp` and `action`, so basically:

`[
   {created_at: 1590357784, action: "Logged In"}, 
   {created_at: 1590357734, action: "Changed Password"}
]`

I was thinking of adding a json field to the data ( `$table->json('user_logs')->nullable();`) but would this be sufficient to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Attribute Casting**.
The `$casts` property on your model provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The `$casts` property should be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the column to. The supported cast types are: `integer`, `real`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`:`<digits>`, `string`, `boolean`, `object`, **array**, `collection`, `date`, `datetime`, and `timestamp`.

To demonstrate attribute casting, let's cast the user_logs attribute, which is stored in our database **as an string** to a array value:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'user_logs' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Now the `user_logs` attribute will always be cast to a `array` when you access it, even if the underlying value is stored in the database as an string:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->user_logs // [{created_at: 1590357784, action: "Logged In"}, {created_at: 1590357734, action: "Changed Password"}]
```

You can also try [Custom Casts](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) And implement your own decoding of a json if that's what you need.